# Why do I have these errors on the OK Button if the code is correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I was ready to test the dialog, but I have the errors from the photo. Why ?

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpiWC.png)

Comment: Please replace all images with text see [ask]

Comment: The name is `OnOK` with a capital "K". Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `OnOK` instead of `OnOk`?

```
CDialog::OnOK   Override to perform the OK button action in a modal dialog box. The default closes the dialog box and DoModal returns IDOK.
```